# Could not resolve host: github.com BeagleBoard Black wireless

Tags: git, beagleboneblack

I am trying to clone my git repository into my BeagleBone black but i get the error

> **fatal: unable to access 'git url'; Could not resolve host: github.com**

When I `ping 8.8.8.8` there is a response however when trying to `ping 'github.com'` it also tells me

> **ping: unknown host github.com**

has anyone encountered something like this?

Answer (score 0):

As the ping to 8.8.8.8 got through, have you tried pinging the ip (192.30.253.112) directly?

If that works it would suggest a problem with the DNS look up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dns server on your environment, check your configuration on the server and probably problem is your dns server can not transmit your dns queries. You can check your dns forwarders and root hints.

If you do not have any dns server, you can try to change your dns to google, opendns or another. Then you can try.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to ping 8.8.8.8, that means that your internet might be working but the actual DNS lookup (how it translates a web address like google.com to the IP address such as 8.8.8.8) is failing.

You might be able to solve this by directly pinging the IP or setting your IP address to be static.

Try following the steps in this:
http://ofitselfso.com/Beagle/NetworkingSetupConnectingTheBeagleboneBlack.php

or

http://derekmolloy.ie/set-ip-address-to-be-static-on-the-beaglebone-black/

Answer (score 0):

I have been breaking my head on this issue for hours. Turns out it is due to a certain `resolv.conf` file.

Check if your `resolv.conf` is red in color (there is a good chance that might be the case) using:

```
ls /etc/resolv.conf
```

If this is the case, execute:

```
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

Add these lines:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Save it, and well - that should do the trick. You can check out the connection using `ping` commands. If, however, you have the file, create an alternate file with the same contents and rename the same, deleting the old `resolv.conf` file.